# Config IntelliJ switch case style

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij keeps formatting my switch case as follows:

```
        switch (enumVal) {
            case X:
                //do stuff
                break;
            case Y:
                //do stuff
                break;
         }
```

But I would like it to be formatted like Sun style:

```
        switch (enumVal) {
        case X:
            //do stuff
            break;
        case Y:
            //do stuff
            break;
         }
```

Is there a way to config that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java, select tab "Wrapping and Braces", scroll down the list to 'switch' statement, uncheck the option "Indent 'case' branches".

More information: [IntelliJ 2016.3 Help - Code Style, Java](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/code-style-java.html)